# Sockets in a "group" setting?

Tags: c++, c, winsock, sockets

Typically you have a server and client pair or two peers that connect to each other through a socket. This is a 1 to 1 relationship.

Lets say you had 6 peers. Is there a way for them to be "grouped" together without a "server" so that 1 peer can send a udp/tcp message directly to another?

I'm basically looking for a way to do this without having to set up a separate socket for each relationship.

If this is possible, what are the correct terms?

Comment: it sounds like you are looking for something like [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP sockets can send data through a non-connected socket using the [`sendto()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  Endpoints specified have to be listening on the given IP/port but do not have to have already initiated a connection.

Comment: So what you're saying is I can have each peer listening on the same port, then have them send a message to the right ip through that port? Is there any performance differences between a connected and non-connected port? Is this related to multicast at all?

Comment: If you want them all listening on the same port, then multicast is exactly what you want.  All your sockets can join the multicast group and any socket can send data that all will receive.

Comment: Choosing the accepted answer was tough because sendto() and multicast were both good answers. However, sendto() was more specific and multicast seems to be reliant on having the same subnet. I'll be using sendto() for sending messages to one or more machines, and broadcast/multicast for detecting computers when on the same subnet.

Answer (score 1):

No easy way with TCP, but with UDP you have [**multicast**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast).

Comment: With a multicast can you selectively decide to send to 1 or a few machines in the group? Assuming this is a software-only solution, any examples (OS X or Linux)?

Comment: Ethernet multicast is actually handled [mostly] in hardware. IP multicast allows given socket to join multiple groups - say, have one group for general communication and several specific groups for whatever application "domains" (really hate these corporate words though). Forewarning - multicast is usually no-go on a WAN since you need explicit switch/router support. As for examples - you'll find plenty of them on the net.

Comment: I'm doing this over LAN. So can you do this without messing with the router/modem settings (pure software), or does this require a special setup on the network?

Comment: It should be fine on the same lan. This is approximately how apple bonjour works.

Comment: Bonjour probably uses broadcast for auto discovery though, right?